# is Proxy class related to proxy design pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface, rmi

there is a class in java called Proxy: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html
As I understood it is used to implement interfaces on runtime.
On the other side when searching for this, I came across a page explaining the proxy design pattern, so are they related in any way? or they are totally separate things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A frequent use of the `Proxy` class is indeed to implement the proxy design pattern in an automated way.

If for example you want to automagically wrap an object inside a proxy with some additional behaviour (let's say rate limiting method calls, but it could really be anything) then `Proxy` lets you do this in a very general way without writing code that's specific to a given class to proxy.

Note that this is not the **only** use of the `Proxy` class however. For example the proxy design pattern is defined in a way that the original object and the proxy have the same interface (i.e. same methods & so on) and that's not necessary for the `Proxy` class. The invocation handler doesn't necessary need to forward the calls to a similarly-"shaped" object, but can do whatever it wants. A common example for this is [constructing mock objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object).